# How do I get an OID from a nested table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've created a Hotel table which also holds a nested table, a collection of rooms.
First I created the Room_type:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ROOM_TYPE AS OBJECT (
       Room_id NUMBER(30),
       RoomDiameter NUMBER(2),
       Price NUMBER(10,4)
);
```

Then I created a collection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ROOMS_TYPE AS TABLE OF ROOM_TYPE;
```

Then the table itself:

```
    CREATE TABLE HOTEL(
      Hotel_id NUMBER(30) PRIMARY KEY,
      Phone    NUMBER(13),
      Rooms    ROOMS_TYPE
)NESTED TABLE Rooms STORE AS HOTEL_ROOMS;
```

Then I wanted to store the OID's in a variable, so I did something like this - I had 6 Rooms in the table with Room_id 1 to 6:

```
Declare
    room_ref_1 REF ROOM_TYPE;
    room_ref_2 REF ROOM_TYPE;
    room_ref_3 REF ROOM_TYPE;
    room_ref_4 REF ROOM_TYPE;
    room_ref_5 REF ROOM_TYPE;
    room_ref_6 REF ROOM_TYPE;
begin
    SELECT REF(R) INTO room_ref_1 FROM HOTEL H, TABLE(H.Rooms) R WHERE R.Room_id = 1;
    SELECT REF(R) INTO room_ref_2 FROM HOTEL H, TABLE(H.Rooms) R WHERE R.Room_id = 2;
    SELECT REF(R) INTO room_ref_3 FROM HOTEL H, TABLE(H.Rooms) R WHERE R.Room_id = 3;
    SELECT REF(R) INTO room_ref_4 FROM HOTEL H, TABLE(H.Rooms) R WHERE R.Room_id = 4;
    SELECT REF(R) INTO room_ref_5 FROM HOTEL H, TABLE(H.Rooms) R WHERE R.Room_id = 5;
    SELECT REF(R) INTO room_ref_6 FROM HOTEL H, TABLE(H.Rooms) R WHERE R.Room_id = 6;
end;
```

In the end I get an error: ORA-00904: "R"."SYS_NC_ROWINFO$": invalid identifier

Comment: I was going to try and help you, but I can't get past the create object statement. "size" is a reserved word and Oracle returns an error when I try to make it a field in the object.

Comment: I changed the size to RoomDiameter - this piece of code is just an example now it should give out the same error, thanks for pointing it out and your effort to help!

Comment: I might need to add an Object View

Comment: Can't reference an object view nvm